# Yoneda lemma natural isomorphism proof question

Tags: category-theory, yoneda-lemma

From Mac Lane:

> Let $K: D \rightarrow \text{Set}$ be a functor with $D$ having small hom sets, the bijection:
>
> $y : \text{Nat}(D(r,-), K) \cong Kr$ by $\alpha : D(r,-) \rightarrow K$ to $\alpha_r 1_r$
>
> is a natural isomorphism $y : N \rightarrow E$ between the functors $E, N : \text{Set}^{D} \times D \rightarrow \text{Set}$,  where $E: \langle K, r \rangle \mapsto Kr$ and $N : \langle K, r \rangle \mapsto \text{Nat}(D(r,-) \rightarrow K)$

I'm trying to show that $y : N \rightarrow E$ is a natural isomorphism but I'm having trouble with one part.

I need to show that for any $\langle F, f \rangle : \langle K, r \rangle \rightarrow \langle K', r' \rangle$: $$E \langle F,f \rangle \circ y_{\langle K, r\rangle} = y_{\langle K', r' \rangle} \circ N \langle F, f \rangle$$ when evaluated at $\alpha : D(r, -) \rightarrow K$.

This should reduce to: $$E \langle F, f \rangle (\alpha_r 1_r) = \alpha ' _{r'} 1_{r'}$$ but I'm having trouble showing the equality between these two things.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: $K'r'$ is a set, $E\langle F,f\rangle(a_r1_r)$ is an element of $K'r'$.

Comment: My mistake, I meant to write $E \langle F, f \rangle (\alpha_r 1_r) = \alpha ' _{r'} 1_{r'}$.  I'll edit that.

Comment: Okay, but what is $\alpha'$? Presumably, it's $N\langle F,f\rangle(\alpha)$, but what is that explicitly?

Comment: Yes, that's what $\alpha ' $ is short for.  It doesn't define explicitly what $N \langle F, f \rangle (\alpha)$ should be, but I would assume it's something of the form $F \circ \alpha \circ D(f, -)$ where $D(f, -): D(r', -) \rightarrow D(r, -)$ for $f: r \rightarrow r'$.  I'm not quite sure if that would be correct and I'm not sure how to show the equality with $E \langle F, f \rangle.$

Comment: Yes, your expansion of $N\langle F,f\rangle(\alpha)$ is correct, but I recommend using $\beta$ instead of $F$ since $F$ is a natural transformation $K\to K'$. Apply the expansion to $1_r$ to get $\beta_{r'}(\alpha_{r'}(f))$. Now what's the expansion of $E\langle\beta,f\rangle$ and what does that expansion look like applied to $\alpha_r1_r$?

Comment: It would seem that $(\beta_{r'}) \circ (Kf)$ would be the proper expansion, but I'm not sure how to evaluate $(\beta_{r'}) \circ (Kf) \circ (\alpha_r 1_r)$ any further.

Comment: You're right about the first expansion, but it is being *applied* to $\alpha_r1_r$ not composed with it. You have $\beta_{r'}((Kf)(\alpha_r1_r))=\beta_{r'}(\alpha_{r'}(f))$ as the meaning of the original equation you are trying to prove. These are equal by naturality of $\alpha$.

Comment: So by the naturality of $\alpha$, $(Kf)(\alpha_r 1_r)=\alpha_{r'}f$, and therefore by postcomposing with $\beta_{r'}$ the equality holds?